# Erro DomPDF Illegal "string offset 'hex' online 1150 style.cls.php"

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dompdf

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])==false){
        echo("<script>window.location = 'login.php';</script>");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
        <title>Relatório</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="img/Brasão_do_Ceará.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo_relatorio.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/w3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var comeco = $("#data_filtroe").val();
            var fim = $("#data_filtrod").val();
            $("input[type='date']").click(function(){
            $("#data_filtrod").attr("min",comeco);
            comeco = $("#data_filtroe").val();
            fim = $("#data_filtrod").val();   
            if(fim<comeco){
                document.querySelector('#data_filtrod').value = comeco;
                $("#data_filtrod").attr("min",comeco);
            }
            });
            $("input[type='date']").change(function(){
            comeco = $("#data_filtroe").val();
            fim = $("#data_filtrod").val();   
            if(fim<comeco){
                document.querySelector('#data_filtrod').value = comeco;
                $("#data_filtrod").attr("min",comeco);
            }
            });
            // $("#datas").click(function(){
            //  $("#status_diat").modal();
            // });
            $("tr").click(function() {
            $('tr').not(this).css( "background-color", "white" );
            $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
            });
            });
            function relatorio_diario(){
            var comeco = $("#data_filtroe").val();
            var fim = $("#data_filtrod").val();
            var turma = $("#turma").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: "status_relatorio.php",
                data: { "comeco": comeco, "fim": fim, "turma": turma },
                success: function(data){
                    document.querySelector('#status_dia').innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
            }
            function verif(){
                if(!($("#status")[0])){ // Verifica se o id status não existe, se não existir ele executa o código
                    alert("Nenhum dado a ser impresso!");
                }else{
                    data = new Date();
                    var datai = $("#data_filtroe").val();
                    var dataf = $("#data_filtrod").val();
                    var turma = $("#turma").val();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'gera_pdf.php',
                        data: { 'datai': datai, 'dataf': dataf, 'turma': turma},
                        success: function( data ){
                            alert(data);   
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
            /* Função Ajax, consulta no banco de dados */
            function mostra_ocorrencias(nome_aluno){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "pesquisa_individual.php",
                data: 'nome_aluno='+nome_aluno,
                success: function( data ){      
                    document.querySelector('#relatorio').innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
                // var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                //  if(xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200){
                //      document.getElementById('relatorio').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //  }
                // };
                // xmlhttp.open("GET","pesquisa_individual.php?nome_aluno="+nome_aluno,true);
                // var rel = xmlhttp.send();
                // document.querySelector('#relatorio').innerHTML = rel; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="caixa" id="menu" title="Voltar ao Menu." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sair_menu">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <br>
        <h4>Menu</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="caixa" title="Filtrar" id="datas" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#status_diat">
        <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x"></i>
        <br>
        <h4>Filtrar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="caixa" title="Gerar PDF" id="pdf" onclick="verif()">
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x"></i>
        <br>
        <h4>PDF</h4>
        </div>
        <h1>Coga</h1>
        <div id="sair_menu" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Deseja Sair de Relatório?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location = 'menu.php';">Sim</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="status_dia" align="center">
        </div>
        <div id="status_diat" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Gerar Relatório:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <label id="textoe">De:</label><input type="date" name="data_filtro" id="data_filtroe" value="<?php 
                            setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
                            date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Fortaleza' );
                            echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
                    <label id="textod">Até:</label><input type="date" name="data_filtro" id="data_filtrod" min="" value="<?php 
                            setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
                            date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Fortaleza' );
                            echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
                    <br><br>
                    <label>Filtrar:</label><select name="turma" id="turma">
                        <option>Todas as Turmas</option>
                        <?php
                            $con = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","eeep_#2017");
                            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                            mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
                            mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
                            mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
                            mysql_select_db("alunos",$con);
                            $sql = "select curso from alunos_turmas group by curso order by curso";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
                            while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                echo "<option>".$linha['curso']."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="relatorio_diario()">Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pesquisa">
        <!-- O attributo oninput executa alguma função jquery ou javascript quando o usuário digita -->
            Pesquisar: <input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#tabela_nome_alunos', '.valores', this.value)" type="text" placeholder="Digite algo sobre o aluno." title="Digite algo sobre o aluno.">
        </div>

        <div align="center" id="tabela_principal">
        <table align="center" id="tabela_nome_alunos">
            <tr id="cabecalho">
                <td>Número</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>Turma</td>
            </tr>
<?php
    $con = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","eeep_#2017");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysql_select_db("alunos",$con);
    $sql = "select * from alunos_turmas group by nome order by curso, numero asc";
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
            <tr style="background-color: white;" id="<?php echo $linha['nome'];?>" class="valores" value="<?php echo $linha['nome'];?>" onclick="mostra_ocorrencias(id)">
                <td><?php echo $linha['numero'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $linha['nome'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $linha['curso'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="center" id="relatorio">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código **gera_pdf.php**:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once ("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $datai = $_POST['datai'];
    $dataf = $_POST['dataf'];
    $turma = "curso='";
    $turma .= $_POST['turma']."'"." and ";
    if($turma=="Todas as Turmas"){
        $turma = "";
    }
    $resultado ="";
    $datas1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$_POST['datai']) -> format('d/m/Y');
    $datas2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$_POST['dataf']) -> format('d/m/Y');
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=alunos", "root", "eeep_#2017"); 
    $result = $con->query("select * from ocorrencias where ".$turma."data>='$datai' and data<='$dataf'");
    $html = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Geração de PDF</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/estilo_gera_pdf.css'>

    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href='./css/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
    <link href='./css/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body onload='print()'>
    <table width='100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Líder</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Turma</th>
                <th>Aluno</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Justificativa</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";
            while ($linha = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                $datamos = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$linha['data']) -> format('d/m/Y');
                $resultado .= "<tr style='background-color: white;' class='valores'><td>".$linha['lider']."</td><td>".$datamos."</td><td>".$linha['curso']."</td><td>".$linha['nome_aluno']."</td><td>".$linha['tipo']."</td>
            <td>"; 
            if($linha['obs']==''){
                $resultado .= '-';
            }else{
                $resultado .= $linha['obs'];
            }
            $resultado .= "</td>
        </tr>";
        }
        $html.=$resultado."</tbody>
    </table>


    <script src='./css/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./css/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./css/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF ();
$dompdf-> load_html ($html);
$dompdf-> render ();
$dompdf-> stream ("sample.pdf");
?>
```

O erro apresentado é este:

> Illegal "string offset 'hex' online 1150 style.cls.php"

Comment: Carlos estou ajustando aqui jsPDF, a documentação deles parece não abranger isto. Assim que conseguir fazer os ajustes eu posto, estou tentando aqui. Até mais.

Comment: Que legal, depois que eu respondi a pergunta que atualizou o cache! Af

Comment: Qual é a versão do *DomPDF* que você está usando ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Segundo a documentação do *jsPDF* o plugin **addHTML** foi descontinuado.

Você pode utilizar o plugin **fromHTML**.

Há uma pequena diferença entre os dois, que é a seguinte:

> **addHTML**

```
/*
 * @param element {Mixed} Elemento HTML, ou qualquer coisa suportada por html2canvas.
 * @param x {Number} iniciando a coordenada X nas unidades declaradas da instância jsPDF.
 * @param y {Number} iniciando a coordenada Y nas unidades declaradas da instância jsPDF.
 * @param options {Object} Opções adicionais, verifique o código abaixo.
 * @param callback {Function} para chamar quando a renderização tiver terminado.
 */
addHTML(element, x, y, options, callback)
```

> **fromHTML**

```
/*
 * @param HTML {String or DOM Element} Texto formatado em HTML ou ponteiro para o elemento DOM que deve ser processado em PDF.
 * @param x {Number} iniciando a coordenada X nas unidades declaradas da instância jsPDF.
 * @param y {Number} iniciando a coordenada Y nas unidades declaradas da instância jsPDF.
 * @param settings {Object} Variáveis adicionais / opcionais que controlam a análise, renderização.
 * @param callback {Function} para chamar quando a renderização tiver terminado.
 */
fromHTML(HTML, x, y, settings, callback, margins)
```

#### Observações

> Nos testes feitos por mim, o método **fromHTML** funcionou na versão *1.0.272* acima desta versão em meus testes ele não aplicou a formatação definida no *CSS*.
>
> Informe o endereço completo para os arquivos **CSS**, exemplo:
>
> http://exemplo.com.br/css/style.css

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script>
// var datai = $("#data_filtroe").val(); // Comentado apenas para teste
// var dataf = $("#data_filtrod").val(); // Comentado apenas para teste
// var turma = $("#turma").val(); // Comentado apenas para teste
$.ajax({
    method: 'get', // Alterei para GET apenas para fins de teste
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wellmotta/f23329f397c4d50a0f286ad488da5760/raw/7da6cf71f38b83d5718e99d796575c6441c5b948/boot_table.html',
    // data: { 'datai': datai, 'dataf': dataf, 'turma': turma}, // Comentado apenas para teste
    success: function(response){
        savePDF(response);
    }
});
function savePDF(codigoHTML) {
    var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4'),
    data = new Date();
    margins = {
        top: 40,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 1000
    };
    doc.fromHTML(codigoHTML,
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { pagesplit: true },
    function(dispose){
        doc.save("Relatorio - "+data.getDate()+"/"+data.getMonth()+"/"+data.getFullYear()+".pdf");
    });
}
</script>
```

> Você pode ver funcionando perfeitamente aqui no [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/navubax)

Comment: Sua resposta entrou na fila de "*Publicações de baixa qualidade*" porque alguém sinalizou ela. Não sei se de fato é ou não uma boa resposta ou não, mas ao menos me parece plausível que seja. No entanto, ao clicar no botão "Executar", não vi nada acontecer. De qualquer forma, vou marcar como "*Parece OK*" na fila de revisão.

Comment: Não aconteceu nada porque precisa do arquivo `gera_pdf.php` como não tem um servidor para executar o arquivo.

Comment: A tabela gerada ela não fica com o width na página inteira como posso deixa-la para ocupar a largura total da página? E quando ele excede a primeira página as próximas não possuem espaçamento de margem no topo... Como posso resolver?