# Problemas ao Gerar PDF com conteúdo escondido com jsPDF e html2canvas

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

Estou tentando gerar um PDF com `js` utilizando `html2canvas` e `jsPDF`. Quando o conteúdo está sendo visualizado, funciona tudo 100%, porém preciso que esse conteúdo fique oculto. Já tentei:

```
- display: none;
- visibility: hidden;
- Position: absolute;
```

Entre outras coisas. Sempre me retorna esse erro quando tento gerar pdf com conteúdo "escondido" na página.

> jspdf.debug.js:2571 Uncaught Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG

Segue abaixo o código usado:

```
<div id="conteudo-pdf">
    Conteúdo
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    $('#btGerarPDF').click(function () {
        doc.addHTML($("#conteudo-pdf"), function(){
            doc.save('arquivo.pdf');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Você precisa exibir a pagina, pois é feito um `print` da tela e colocado no `PDF`

Comment: Monte uma versão "para impressão" da página sem o conteúdo que deseja ocultar.

Comment: Mude `.addHTML` para `.fromHTML` e baixe a [biblioteca](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) mais recente: `var html = $("#conteudo-pdf").contents();`

Answer (score 1):

A um tempo atrás eu [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242271/60376) essa pergunta [Erro - jsPDF Geração de PDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240131), hoje ela esta com outro título, pode ser que não esteja funcionando devido você estar utilizando o plugin **addHTML** que foi descontinuado.

> Para saber mais recomendo que leia a resposta que dei na pergunta citada.

#### Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnPDF').click(function() {
      savePDF(document.querySelector('#documento'));
    });
});
  
function savePDF(codigoHTML) {
  var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');
    data = new Date();
    margins = {
        top: 40,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 1000
    };
    doc.fromHTML(codigoHTML,
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { pagesplit: true },
    function(dispose){
        doc.save("Relatorio - "+data.getDate()+"/"+data.getMonth()+"/"+data.getFullYear()+".pdf");
    });
}
```

```css
#documento {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="documento">Esse conteúdo esta ocultado no navegador, mas ao gerar o <strong>PDF</strong> ele irá aparecer!</div>

<button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnPDF">Gerar PDF</button>
```