# Javascript com PHP para gerar um PDF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

Estou com uma tabela dinâmica em *JavaScript*. Preciso mandar para o *PHP* todos os itens que foram adicionados nela e gerar um *PDF* com a classe *mPDF*.

Alguém poderia ajudar.

Código HTML/Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/Zharor/sumt8603/

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
$item = utf8_encode($_POST['item']);<br>
$descricao = utf8_encode($_POST['descricao']);<br>
$unidade = utf8_encode($_POST['unidade']);<br>
$pedido = utf8_encode($_POST['pedido']);<br>

//PEGA O ARQUIVO MODELO<br>
$pdf = file_get_contents("modelo.html");<br>

//SUBSTITUI COM OS DADOS FORNECIDOS<br>
$pdf = str_replace("#item","$item",$pdf);<br>
$pdf = str_replace("#descricao","$descricao",$pdf);<br>
$pdf = str_replace("#unidade","$unidade",$pdf);<br>
$pdf = str_replace("#pedido","$pedido",$pdf);<br>

//SOLICITA A CLASS MPDF<br>
require_once("mpdf/mpdf.php");<br>

//INSTANCIA A CLASS MPDF<br>
$mpdf = new mPDF( );<br>

//ESCREVE O PDF<br>
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdf);<br>
ob_clean();<br>

//SAIDA DO PDF NO NAVEGADOR<br>
$mpdf->Output();<br>
?>
```

Estou usando Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Tem que ser ao lado do servidor ? Não pode ser ao lado do cliente ? Tenho essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257302/60376) e essa [outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242271/60376) sobre gerar PDF usando a biblioteca *jsPDF*.

Comment: não mando para o servidor não, só quero que crie um pdf com os itens que estão na tabela, pode me ajudar nesse jsPDF ? obrigado pela resposta